# Rails check for value in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is simple, but I've tried several ways and I can't get it to work.

I have an array of zip codes in my model. Using a before save callback I want to check if the zip code in the current shipping address matches any of the zip codes in the array.

Model

```
class ShippingAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :set_green


  def green_zip_codes
    ['33432','33333']
  end


  def set_green
    if green_zip_codes.include? self.zipcode
      self[:green] = true 
    end  
  end 


end
```

If I change this:

```
  def set_green
    if green_zip_codes.include? self.zipcode
      self[:green] = true 
    end  
  end
```

To this:

```
  def set_green
    if green_zip_codes.include?("33333")
      self[:green] = true 
    end  
  end
```

it works, but obviously, I would like to check the zip code of the current entry.

**EDITED**
This is the way it works for what I'm trying to do:

```
  def set_green
    if green_zip_codes.include?(self.zipcode.to_s)
      self[:green] = true
    end
  end
```

Comment: When it doesn't work, do you get an error? If so what is the error?

Comment: I don't get an error. It just does not evaluate to true. Basically, I want to make green true if the current zip code matches any of the zip codes in the green_zip_codes array.

Comment: Ok, but it has to do with the value of `self.zipcode` at the time of evaluation. If you add `puts self.zipcode` to the `set_green` method you should see the value it returns printed in the web console.

Comment: chances are self.zipcode either has some extra chars in it (most likely a newline), or it's not a string.  Rather than `puts`, try `p`, which will give some more clarity most of the time.

Comment: added like this: 
if green_zip_codes.include? puts.self.zipcode
and it evaluates to true in the console.

Comment: Not quite what I was thinking but it shows what @SomeGuy is getting at. You could use `self.zipcode.to_s` as that is more reliable and readable. But I would either store the zips as the same format as the return value of `self.zipcode` or make the `self.zipcode` return a string. The `to_s` seems a little hackish.

Comment: Would be easier to see if you included the code for the `.zipcode` method. If it is just a column in the table, you could check the migration to see what format the column is (Integer, string, etc.)

Comment: the value is a string I can see it in the console. Now I'm getting this error: undefined method `self' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? itself

Comment: Careful - your before_save may inadvertently return false, preventing you from saving.

Comment: What is `self[:green]`? Is `green` an attribute of the model? If so, try using `self.green = true` in the `set_green` method.

Comment: You don't show how the record is created / saved. Add that code, please (including example attributes).

Comment: Thank you Beartech and everyone else for helping out. I've edited the question with the solution that works for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes Brian, it does prevent from saving when false. What would you recommend to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If `green` is an attribute of the model, then the `set_green` method should be:

```
def set_green
  if green_zip_codes.include?("33333")
    self.green = true 
  end
  true # to ensure true is returned to the before_save callback even when the zip code does not match.
end
```

Comment: The execution in halted only if a callback returns `false` or raises an exception.